# How to export character from Zbrush to Blender?

Tags: 3d, blender, zbrush

Zbrush displays only 1 format (zpr), which Blender doesn’t accept((

Comment: I'm surprised you can't export to `.obj`...

Comment: [Typing "export from zbrush to blender" into a search engine is turning up some promising-looking guides and walkthroughs](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=export+from+zbrush+to+blender). Which of these documented methods did you try so far, and where specifically did you run into trouble?